# Reopening the link in same tab , the tab focus is not shifting to the new tab?

Tags: angularjs, window.open

I have `used window.open().focus`, but it is not working correctly? I have written following code in javascript file in a function call?

I am opening a disclaimer on click and checking foe that disclaimer window only

```
if ($sessionStorage.MAHwindow == undefined){
    $sessionStorage.MAHwindow = window.open(disclaimerUrl, "mahWindow");
} else if ($sessionStorage.MAHwindow.closed==false){
    $sessionStorage.MAHwindow = window.open(disclaimerUrl,"mahWindow").focus();
} else {
    $sessionStorage.MAHwindow = window.open(disclaimerUrl, "mahWindow");
}
```

Comment: Needs more details. which browser are you using? Can you make a fiddle of the behavior and share? Looks like this has been asked multiple times before, you might want to look into those.

Comment: Browser is chrome only. Yes it has been asked multiple times, but none of those covers this particular issue?

Comment: AFAIK tab focus doesn't shift automatically unless specified in the settings - "change focus on opening a new tab" is there in all modern browsers. You can consider opening a new window, then that might be possible.

Comment: I have added tab activate extension in chrome, it is working for other links . But for my link it is same only (not working).